# Is it possible to put a file in 'Downloads' folder in Android AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

My app needs to configure settings for the user by reading from a one-time user profile config file at Downloads folder (when the app is run for the 1st time). I cannot figure out where to put that test config file in the Studio AVD emulated device. I tried created a 'test' folder in the Downloads folder in AVD device, and thought it might show up somewhere in the .android/ where AVD devices seem to be. But, can't find nothing..

Is it possible to put a file in AVD for test & use by the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,just drag your file into AVD window,it will be copied to Downloads folder automatically.

Or you can use adb command to do that like following picture
[image: adb push file into avd]

Comment: This is so much easier than uploading to google-drive then download to the AVD again.. Thanks so much for this help!

Comment: Then please accept my answer and up vote it,that will be appreciated.

Comment: It said the vote was recorded but cannot be shown because my repute point is less than 15.. sorry aolphn

Comment: And choose my answer ,choose ✔ before my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In Android Studio, select the Device File Explorer Window (usually bottom right).  Make sure the Device you want is selected at the top in the dropdown.  In the directory tree find your Downloads folder (or any folder you like), right-click and select Upload...  Then you can navigate to the file you want to upload to your device.